# Consume WCF service from go application

Tags: wcf, go

Is it even possible more or less natively consume `WCF` service from Go application?

I can imagine it should be possible to execute `SOAP` calls in Go, but `WCF` is a bit more than that only, for example authorization will probably be a problem also...

Have anyone at least approached this area, or maybe someone can give useful me advice in this "wheel reinvention task"?

Thank you in advance for all your input, ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should expose a RESTful Service. I myself have the problem with exposing a WCF Service too many clients using PHP, Go, Ruby and all kind of languages. We never ever got it right, to automatically generate a proxy.

The maybe simplest way is to use WCF, like described in this example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-
By-Step-Guide

But I recommend to switch to ASP.NET Core (Migration is not that hard) or if you have the budget I would consider https://servicestack.net/

Answer (score 0):

It may be well beyond the wait time for this. However, here is something really interesting that could help. The situation the authors found themselves is relevant even today in some organizations.

https://github.com/khoad/msbingo

Here's the motivation provided by the authors:

Application/soap+msbin1 encoding was a blocking issue for modernizing services from WCF to platform-agnostic technologies such as Go. *We needed to be able to make calls to dependency services that spoke msbin1 and were not going to be updated or even reconfigured*, but we did not want to introduce unnecessary complexity such as workarounds like .NET-based WCF request translator proxies or deploying Mono with our service instances. Initially we tried the Mono deployment route, which, while it would have worked well enough, significantly complicated our deployment pipeline, thus erasing one of the major advantages of golang.

I found it a useful starting point to begin experimentation.